# Assigned macro to control button that works on its own worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have several worksheets that have a Control Button that is assigned the same macro. I need the macro to only work on the worksheet that it is on. It is currently sending me back to the first worksheet when I click on these buttons, regardless of which worksheet I am on. I am new to VBA so I am having a hard time understanding all of the macro, but mainly I don't understand the Application.Goto line and think that is where my trouble is. This code is written by someone else, but I am only trying to reverse-engineer / fix it for my own use. I have no idea why it is using the reference of "FirstTime". It is not one of the names of the worksheets or excel filename.

```
Sub Break()
    Application.Goto Reference:="FirstTime"
    Do Until ActiveCell = ""
    If ActiveCell <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
    Loop
    
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Enter client engagement")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Now()
    Else
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Now()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Work performed/tasks completed")
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I've tried using other strings or removing any Reference from Application.GoTo, but it only gives me a 1004 error. It also seems to need this line, otherwise it also causes an error. The rest of the code/macro works as intended as far as I can, it's just a matter of going to the wrong worksheet when the Control Button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you exactly understood your own problem by yourself.

When you execute `Application.Goto Reference:="FirstTime"`, it goes to the range that was named `FirstTime`, which most likely in what you call "the first worksheet".

On the left of the formula bar, as shown in the screenshow below, you have a dropdown, you can use it to check the name.

[image]

If I am right so far, follow this procedure:

1. In the sheet where you want your macro to apply, **select** the range you want to call `FirstTime`.
   This range should most likely cover as many rows/columns as the one you should have spotted with my instructions above (it may even be the very same address).
2. Go to menu Formula > Name manager.
3. Click New.
4. Fill the window with:

   - Name = `FirstTime`
   - Scope = The worksheet you are currently on.
   - Refers to = The range you have selected (the worksheet on that range is expected to be the same as for field Scope).

This will make it so the new name you are defining has higher priority when executing `Application.Goto`.